# Accuracy, Precision and Recall are exactly the same during training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, image-classification, precision-recall

I am training a Binary classification model with Tensorflow 2.8.
I pass the following metrics: ['accuracy', tf.keras.metrics.Precision(), tf.keras.metrics.Recall()] but on every epoch accuracy, precision and recall are exactly the same.
[image]

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66128158/765091. Note especially *"The problem of having equal TP and TN lies on the use of labels formatted as one-hot encoded vectors for binary classification"* - maybe that's the case for your model?

Answer (score 0):

A same value for Precision and Recall is possible when False Positives is equal to False Negatives. It doesn't mean that the model is incorrect.